# CASE...WHEN statement - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am having a world of difficult with using a CASE...WHEN statement.

I am working on building a small database for my company and we are looking at sales orders. By default, our tracking system classifies our orders into one of 10 categories, but we are primarily concerned with 3: A, B, and C orders. My code looks like:

```
SELECT 
    ORDER_NUM,
    BUYER_NUM, 
    CREATOR_NUM
    (CASE
        WHEN ORDER_CD = 'A' THEN 'Part'
        WHEN ORDER_CD = 'B' THEN 'Service'
        WHEN ORDER_CD = 'C' THEN 'Labor'
        ELSE 'Other'
    ) AS ORDER_TYPE
FROM tbl_ORDER
WHERE ORDER_DATE > '01-Jan-2017'
```

However, I keep getting "Missing Expression" errors. Could somebody please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: you forgot to `END` the `case` expression.

Comment: A comma(`,`) is missing after `CREATOR_NUM`

Comment: I will mention that, if `A` always denotes `Part`, etc., then it would be preferable for this correspondence to be stored in a related table, and have the descriptive titles retrieved with a join.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala thank you!

Comment: @Wanderer I made the rookie error of not double checking before I posted, I'm normally not that bad :) Thanks!

Comment: @AndyG Unfortunately, we have no control over what our IT team / DBA does :( But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `END` and a comma.  I would also recommend using ISO standard date formats:

```
 SELECT ORDER_NUM, BUYER_NUM, CREATOR_NUM,
        (CASE WHEN ORDER_CD = 'A' THEN 'Part'
              WHEN ORDER_CD = 'B' THEN 'Service'
              WHEN ORDER_CD = 'C' THEN 'Labor'
              ELSE 'Other'
         END) AS ORDER_TYPE
FROM tbl_ORDER
WHERE ORDER_DATE > DATE '2017-01-01';
```

Comment: Hi, Gordon. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you for explaining where I erred, and for your suggestion on the date formatting. Thanks again!